# c++ xml data binding

Tags: c++, xml, data-binding, serialization

There are several comparisons of the different java xml data binding tools online.  I'd like to see this become a useful comparison between the different c++ tools for xml data binding.

Which tool are you using for xml data binding in c++ ?  CodeSynthesis and xmlbeanscxx are a couple of the available choices.

I'd like everyone to add information below about their experience with this technology including reasoning to choose one tool over another, ease of use, and performance.  Also feel free to add technical information regarding namespace support, parsing options(tree/streaming), etc.

---

### [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/)

(Feel free to add Information Here)

License: GPL2 with exceptions / Proprietary

Cons: generated code should be opensourced.

---

### [xmlbeanscxx](https://github.com/rafalrusin/xmlbeansxx)

(Feel free to add Information Here)

License: Apache

Cons:

- has no public issue tracker
- [Incubator page](http://incubator.apache.org/xmlbeanscxx/) is not active (project seems to be abandoned)
- [Project page](http://xmlbeansxx.touk.pl/) is not available (404)

---

### [Boost Serialization Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

(Feel free to add Information Here)

License: Boost

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the open-source [GSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2) toolkit from SourceForge for XML C++ auto-serialization. Also works for plain C. It binds C/C++ to XML schemas automatically and is fully compliant with industry standards for XML, WSDL, SOAP, REST, XML-RPC, JSON, and WS-* protocols. It's pretty efficient too.

Comment: I second this. The docs are a bit strange, but it's mostly all in there.

Answer (score 1):

[Codalogic LMX](http://www.codalogic.com/lmx/)

It has a free version and paid license version as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost Serialization Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) Boost, don't leave home without it.

Comment: Boost Serialization does serialization, not XML data binding.  In other words, you cannot generate code from your schema.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulCoccoli are you sure about this??