# XML to struct in c++

Tags: c++, xml, struct

Looking for something that can take an xml file and turn it into a struct like this.

```
typedef struct XMLpage{
    string type;
    string names[];
    string text;
    int Pos;

    struct XMLpage *Pages[];
}; XMLpage
```

Basically i have a page that could contain other pages that could contain other pages and the plan was to have it read from an xml file and output it as a struct to be used later in someway.

Comment: You may want to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802208/jaxb-equivalent-for-generating-c-classes-from-xsd

Answer (score 0):

I used to use xerces and use SAX, DOM Parsers provided by it, parse and store it in Class/Struct.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/), I've used this library a lot and I'm heavily satisfied. It's reading the XML into a convenient object structure which you can easily read/manipulate.

You'll have to write some simple code for putting the data in your struct, but it is well worth it.